# Set a Class on Ng-Click in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I would like to set a class for an element using ng-click. However although ng-click sets the value correctly it can't be picked up on the same element using ng-class:

```
 <button class="button"  ng-click="selected=2;"  ng-class="{active:selected==2}"> </button>
```

The above code would change the value for $scope.selected but ng-class can only seem to pick this up if it is set by the ng-click of another element.

Answer (score 1):

try it like this

```
<button class="button"  ng-click="selected=2"  ng-class="{'active':selected==2}"> </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The code is working fine. Here is a working fiddle so that you can check out where you getting it wrong.

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Ab4M/)

Code snippet:

```
<button class="button"  ng-click="selected=2"  ng-class="{active:selected==2}">Click to add class </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

For good measure, separate your assignments from the view into the controller.

Controller:

```
app.controller('ctrl', function () {

  $scope.select = function (index) {
    $scope.selected = index;
  };

  $scope.isSelected = function (index) {
    return $scope.selected === index;
  };

});
```

Markup:

```
<button class="button" ng-click="select(2)" ng-class="{ 'active': isSelected(2) }">
```

JsBin: http://jsbin.com/cajubixu/1/